# Log Every File Access Attempt on a System and Sort it by User/System Account

Tags: c#, .net, iis, application-pool

I have a strange issue where I need to see why my application pool is crashing due to a permissions issue and no logs are helpful. Is there any way to log every file access attempt on a system and sort it by the user/system account that tried to access it, especially if it fails in accessing the desired file? Even if there are third party applications for this, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you already try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) by Sysinternals/Microsoft will show that and a lot of other activities.